# Trigger problem, it compiles fine, but when i try to update data it does not triggerr the text message

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

Im creating this trigger and it there is no errors.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER InformacjaAkcji
after insert or update or delete on Zegarek
begin
if inserting then
dbms_output.put_line('Pomyślnie wprowadzono dane ');
end if;
if updating then
dbms_output.put_line('Pomyślnie zaktualizowano dane ');
end if;
if deleting then
dbms_output.put_line('Pomyślnie usunięto dane ');
end if; 
end;
```

Then when i want to trigger it and check if it work i enter this :

```
 Update Zegarek
 Set Cena = 3499 Where NumerSeryjny = 'QT451264CT'
```

And again it says The row is updated sucessfull, but i dont see the text prompt that should be triggerd by :

```
if updating then
dbms_output.put_line('Pomyślnie zaktualizowano dane ');
end if;
```

Where is the problem?, thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you missed to enable the output.

Trigger:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER InformacjaAkcji
  2     AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
  3     ON Zegarek
  4  BEGIN
  5     IF INSERTING
  6     THEN
  7        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Pomyślnie wprowadzono dane ');
  8     END IF;
  9
 10     IF UPDATING
 11     THEN
 12        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Pomyślnie zaktualizowano dane ');
 13     END IF;
 14
 15     IF DELETING
 16     THEN
 17        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line ('Pomyślnie usunięto dane ');
 18     END IF;
 19  END;
 20  /

Trigger created.
```

This is what you're missing:

```
SQL> SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
```

Update:

```
SQL> UPDATE Zegarek
  2     SET Cena = 3499
  3   WHERE NumerSeryjny = 'QT451264CT';
Pomyślnie zaktualizowano dane                     --> here it is!

1 row updated.

SQL>
```

Comment: And note that dbms_output just writes to a buffer. It is up to the client on whether or not to do anything with it.  Thus, dbms_output should only be used as a debugging tool, not something to rely on in production code.

Comment: Also, how you enable dbms_output will depend on the client application. It's different in PL/SQL Developer, for example, or in perl or python.